# Jump not signed instruction in c

Tags: c, assembly, x86

```
test ecx,ecx
jns 00400000
```

is this assembly code equivalent to this c code?

```
int ECX;
if((ECX>>31)==1){..}
```

if not how can I make it equivalent?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ummmm, how about `if (ecx < 0)`?

Comment: `unsigned int ECX` does

Comment: Your C code may be concidered as equivalent.

Comment: @Dakorn: On most implementations, `(ECX>>31)==1` is always false, because `>>` on signed integers is treated as arithmetic shift, yielding `(ECX>>31)==-1`.

Comment: @rslemos: +1, any code attempting to do this kind of emulation of machine instruction logic should be using unsigned types. Signed types are full of implementation-defined and undefined behaviors when it comes to the sorts of things you'll want to do for this type of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based the Wikipedia entry for the [test instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_%28x86_instruction%29), the test will set the sign flag of the flags register based on the most significant bit of the register `ecx`.

Therefore, the jump is taken iff the `MSB` is not set as you have seen. Your complement `C` code is almost equivalent, but depending on whether `>>` does a logical or arithmetic shift, you should mask it to be safe.

```
if(((ECX>>31) & 1)==1){..}
```

Of course, as Jester mentioned, if the signed bit is set, then it is also true that `ECX < 0`, so that is a simpler test in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `test reg,reg` instruction sets flags and that is equivalent to doing a compare in C. So as Jester mentioned `reg < 0` means, is the sign bit set.

However, in C you have to be careful about the variable type you are dealing with. In your case, you'd want to use a type such as `int32_t`. That way you make sure that you are testing a 32 bit integer. The same code on a 64 bit platform may transform your `int` in 64 bits and the sign would be a little further up.

Using a shift in C when you just to a test in assembly is really not equivalent. Actually, if you really wanted to use a shift, you should use an unsigned integer:

```
if((uint32_t)reg >> 31) { ... }
```

But really, that's not sensible and much harder to read than the simple:

```
if(reg < 0) { ... }
```

Not only that, it will be slower (2 instructions instead of 1, although the compiler may figure out that `test reg,reg + jns` would be enough, but you shouldn't count on it.)